# Link C++ with statically , libraries not found

Tags: c++, g++, static-linking

I want to link a g++ binary with the `-static` flag but I get this error
I am using fedora 29

**ERROR**

```
/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lstdc++
/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lm
/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lc
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
```

**Code**

```
#include <iostream>

int main(){
    std::cout << "Hello" << std::endl;


    return 0;
}
```

**G++ line**

```
g++ static.cc -o static -static
```

Comment: I think that on your system the libraries stdc++ m and c are dynamic only

Comment: What OS are you using? Though, I'm guessing you're using Linux.

Comment: How can I make them static? @ThomasSablik

Comment: Yes , fedora 29  @SeanFrancisN.Ballais

Comment: Does this command find some libraries: `find /usr -name "libstdc++.a*"`

Comment: @ThomasSablik Yes it returns me /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-redhat-linux/8/32/libstdc++.a but when I find it in nautilus it seems to be a broken link

Comment: Try you install or reinstall libstdc++-static. On Centos it's `yum install libstdc++-static`

Comment: Wow, thanks, that solved the first line, now at least it can find libstdc++ @ThomasSablik

Comment: I don't know where my static libraries come from, if I installed them or if they were installed by default. After searching the internet I think that your build tools are broken. Maybe you need to reinstall your build environment.

Comment: Yes, it might be, thank you. I solved the other two lines with yum install glibc-static
@ThomasSablik

Comment: Hey, @polmonroig. You might want to answer your own question and not just adding it in in the question itself. :)

Comment: Oh, thanks, did not know I could do that jajaja @SeanFrancisN.Ballais

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to Thomas I found the solution in the comments executing

```
yum install glibc-static
yum install libstdc++-static
```